# Specific treatment for the first and last element of sequence in a function?

Tags: notation

Let $A = \langle a_1,\dots,a_n \rangle$ be a sequence. I have a function that given any element $a_k$ it will return the values of $a_{k-1}+a_k+a_{k+1}$ with the exception of the first and last element that is going to return $a_k + a_{k+1}$ for the first element and $a_k + a_{k-1}$ for the last one:

$ f(k) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    a_k + a_{k+1} & \quad \text{if $k=1$}\\
    a_k + a_{k-1} & \quad \text{if $k=n$}\\
    a_{k-1}+a_k+a_{k+1} & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$

Is there any better (more compact) way of writing this function?

Comment: The big cases block may end up more confusing than just $a_{k-1}+a_k+a_{k+1}$. To clarify how it is defined at the extremes you could just mention it in text.

Comment: If you do want to define it completely, you could also set $a_0=a_{n+1}=0$ and just leave $0$ and $n+1$ out of the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write this as

> For $1\le k\le n$ let $f(k)=a_{k-1}+a_k+a_{k+1}$, with the convention that $a_0=a_{n+1}=0$.

Note that this formulation even covers the case $n=1$ correctly (which the cases-statement does not).

Comment: I agree! Short and sweet.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I would have to define two "special cases" for $a_0$ and $a_n$!